# link 2sd working but apps not move to sd card

Tags: external-sd, link2sd

I created second partition on sd card. But when I mood apps to sd it's showing insufficient storage available on sd card. But my sd card total blank

Comment: May sound like a stupid question, but did you also format the new partition? Without having a file system (i.e. being "formatted"), it is not useable for the system to store files on it.

Answer (score 1):

link2sd will not move apps to sdcard but it will link  2nd partition with system

1)Format your 2nd partition of sdcard  and try it